# Jquery, how to know when input have a :invalid selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have this code:

HTML

```
<input type="text" data-value="1" data-type="input-records" placeholder="Value" pattern="\d{1,4}$" />
```

CSS

```
input[type=text]:invalid { background-color: red; }
```

Javascript

```
$("[data-type=input-records]").die().live("keypress", function (e) {
    if (!($(this).val().length + 1) < 5) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    // More code below...
});
```

I want to make a validation like this:

```
if (!$(this).hasSelector(":invalid")) {
    showMessage("Invalid value");
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function to test for the `:invalid` pseudoclass:

```
if ($(this).is(":invalid")) {
    showMessage("Invalid value");
}
```

**Example:** http://jsbin.com/ikuwur/2/edit