# .length is 1 in IE and 0 in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am using HTML 5 form validation, I am using the `select:invalid` selector.

In Chrome it is counting correctly so it is counting the length of `select:invalid` elements, in IE it is counting with always +1 ahead, so in Chrome `n = 0` but IE `n = 1` and can never reach 0.

Therefore my code below doesn't work on IE. Is there any way around this?

```
$('button').addClass("disabled");
$('form').change(function() {
    var n = $("select:invalid").length;
    if (n === 0) {
      $('button').removeClass("disabled");
    } else if (n > 0){
      $('button').addClass("disabled");
    }
    console.log(n);
});
```

Comment: What element is being selected by "select:invalid" in IE? Can you supply a small working example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: when is this code called?

Comment: :invalid pseudo class works with IE10. See Browser Support section of this page : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/i/invalid/. What is your IE version?

Comment: What versions of jQuery and IE?

Comment: In your title you say ".length is 0 in IE and 1 in chrome" but in your body you say "so in Chrome n = 0 but IE n = 1". You seem a little confused about the results of your test!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14384642/338068 suggests that `:invalid` does work (with a demo backing it up).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan see this stack post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820780/jquery-support-invalid-selector.

Comment: My mistake. @L.A. That post says that it doesn't work and tells you to use methods that rely on querySelectorAll under the hood, or write your own selector extension. I guess in more modern versions of jQuery (as those examples above are now several years old) it has been fixed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan as you say, the solution migth be the latest JQuery version.