# Shiny R: Alert message or modal dialog input:invalid

Tags: html, css, r, validation, shiny

I am developing a simple app, and I would like it to create a pop up in case some of the inputs is invalid. Following the linked response in [#1656](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1656#issuecomment-302899587), I have the following example that allows for some nice background colour in case of an invalid input (for my 300 variables):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML("
    input:invalid {
  background-color: #FFCCCC;
                  }")),

  numericInput("myValue", "My Variable", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.5),
  numericInput("myValue2", "My Variable2", min = 0, max = 3, step = 0.5, value = 0.5),
  textOutput("text"),
  textOutput("text2")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderText(input$myValue)
  output$text2 <- renderText(input$myValue2)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The tag `tags$style("input:invalid{ ... }")),` helps a lot, however I would like to have a bootstrap alert instead of just the change of the background colour.

Essentially, I need to have in the `input:invalid{}` the following div class in some way (I have 300 variables to check):

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <strong>Danger!</strong> Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action.
</div>
```

I would be really glad to hear some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Here is your example with alerts for invalid entries based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384593/jquery-how-to-know-when-input-have-a-invalid-selector). The alert can be triggered once the user clicks out of the input box ([`blur`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp)) or after the user finishes typing ([`keyup`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keyup.asp)). `keyup` may be more useful for this example.

```
library(shiny)

alert <- '$(document).ready(function() {
            $(function () {
             $("input").keyup(function () {
                 if ($(this).is(":invalid")) {
                     alert(\'invalid!\');
                     }
                 });
             });
         })'

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML(alert))),
    tags$style(HTML("
                    input:invalid {
                    background-color: #FFCCCC;
                    }")),
    numericInput("myValue", "My Variable", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.5),
    numericInput("myValue2", "My Variable2", min = 0, max = 3, step = 0.5, value = 0.5),
    textOutput("text"),
    textOutput("text2")
    )

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$text <- renderText(input$myValue)
    output$text2 <- renderText(input$myValue2)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Here are a few options:

1. shiny: [`modalDialog`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modal-dialogs.html) or [`showNotification`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/notifications.html)
2. shinyjs: [`alert`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyjs/vignettes/shinyjs-example.html)
3. shinyBS: [`bsAlert`](https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Alerts.html) --- try running `bsExamples("Alerts")` for an example

---

Here is your sample app with examples of these functions. Note that `shinyjs` and `shinyBS` require adding statements to the ui and server, but `modalDialog` only requires adding statements on the server. `session` also needs to be included in the server function for `shinyBS` to work.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$style(HTML("
                    input:invalid {
                    background-color: #FFCCCC;
                    }")),
    #### Set up shinyjs ####
    useShinyjs(),

    ### shinyBS ###
    bsAlert("alert"),

    numericInput("myValue", "My Variable", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.5),
    numericInput("myValue2", "My Variable2", min = 0, max = 3, step = 0.5, value = 0.5),
    textOutput("text"),
    textOutput("text2")
    )

server <- function(session, input, output) {
    output$text <- renderText({

        ### shinyBS ###
        if(!(is.na(input$myValue)) && (input$myValue > 1 | input$myValue < 0)) {
            createAlert(session, "alert", "myValueAlert", title = "shinyBS: Invalid input",
                        content = "'My Variable' must be between 0 and 1", style = "danger")
        } else {
            closeAlert(session, "myValueAlert")
            return(input$myValue)
        }
        })
    output$text2 <- renderText(input$myValue2)

    ### modalDialog ###
     observeEvent(input$myValue, {
         if(!is.na(input$myValue) && (input$myValue > 1 | input$myValue < 0)) {
             showModal(modalDialog(
                 title = "modalDialog: Invalid input",
                 "'My Variable' must be between 0 and 1"
             ))   
         }
     })

    ### shinyjs ###
    observeEvent(input$myValue, {
        if(!(is.na(input$myValue)) && (input$myValue > 1 | input$myValue < 0)) {
            alert("shinyJS: 'My Variable' must be between 0 and 1")
        }
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks @blondeclover but this does not work for me. I have implemented these solutions, but I have around 300 variables, which makes the use of the the `input:invalid` class rather imperative.

Comment: @ManosC see the edited answer -- let me know if this works for you

Comment: @ManosC No worries, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

If all your inputs start with "myValue", you can select all of them with:

```
$('input[id^="myValue"]')
```

I've firstly tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[id^="myValue"]').on("invalid", function(){alert("invalid");});
})
```

but for some reason that doesn't work.

My second attempt:

```
library(shiny)
js <- '$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[id^=\\\"myValue\\\"]").on("keyup", function(){
  if($(this)[0].checkValidity()){
    $(this).tooltip("destroy");
  }else{
    $(this).tooltip({title:"invalid"});
  }
})
})
'
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(js)
  ),
  numericInput("myValue", "My Variable", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.5),
  numericInput("myValue2", "My Variable2", min = 0, max = 3, step = 0.5, value = 0.5),
  textOutput("text"),
  textOutput("text2")
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderText(input$myValue)
  output$text2 <- renderText(input$myValue2)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It works but I get some errors in the console when the input is valid. I don't know why.

Comment: Hey @Stéphane Laurent, this is very close to what I had in mind but the response of blondeclover is really to the point and rather more inclusive for future reference. Thus I am selecting it for being the closest to what I needed :)
Thanks a lot for the effort